# INSERT Statement to fill in missing rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a list of customers and a number of templates that need to be associated with each customer.  What I'm trying to do is make sure that each customer that has missing templates gets them inserted but I'm having difficulty trying to write a statement which figures out which customers have templates missing.

In the below data set I've got 5 customers and 3 templates.  How could I go about finding the missing templates to achieve the data set at the very bottom?

```
Customers
CustID, Name
C001, John
C002, Jack
C003, Jim
C004, Jill
C005, Julie
-------------------------------

Templates
CustID, TemplateID
C001, T001
C001, T002
C001, T003
C002, T001
C002, T002
C002, T003
C003, T001
C003, T003
C004, T003
-------------------------------

Templates
CustID, TemplateID
C001, T001
C001, T002
C001, T003
C002, T001
C002, T002
C002, T003
C003, T001
C003, T002
C003, T003
C004, T001
C004, T002
C004, T003
C005, T001
C005, T002
C005, T003


----
```

I don't expect the whole insert statement but if you can help me figure out how to find the missing rows that we would be awesome.

Comment: Table names are a bit confusing in your example. If `Customers` contains customers only, `Templates` should in the same way have templates only. The bridge table (the one that contains links to both entities) should be named differently, probably mentioning both entities, perhaps `CustomersTemplates` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Join + Except will do.  [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ad31/1)

```
-- Now you can see how it works in 2012!
CREATE TABLE Customers (
     CustID varchar(6) primary key, 
     Name varchar(20) 
);

INSERT INTO Customers VALUES
('C001', 'John'),
('C002', 'Jack'),
('C003', 'Jim'),
('C004', 'Jill'),
('C005', 'Julie');

CREATE TABLE TemplatesID 
    (
     TemplateID varchar(6) primary key 
    );

INSERT INTO TemplatesID

VALUES ('T001'),('T002'),('T003');


CREATE TABLE Templates (
  TemplateID varchar(6) ,
  CustID varchar(6)
);

INSERT INTO Templates
VALUES
('T001','C001'),
('T001', 'C002');
```

The query

```
select TemplateID,CustID from Customers join TemplatesID on 1!=0 
EXCEPT
select TemplateID,CustID from Templates
```

Comment: You have only partially answered the question. Most of your answer is DDL which will only serve to confuse the OP.

Comment: @sarin, that's not fair if you have this comment 3 minutes after the real example I provided! It took me a couple of minutes to try it on SQL 2012.

Answer (score 0):

So, start with a list of all possible combinations of templates and customers..

```
Select Customers.CustId, AllTemplates.TemplateId
From AllTemplates
CROSS JOIN Customers
```

then compare the current list you have with the list of all possible combinations using a left join and any where you get a NULL in the left join you have found a missing template!

```
With AllPossibleCustomerTemplate as (
    Select Customers.CustId, Templates.TemplateId
    From Templates
    CROSS JOIN Customers
)
Select AllPossibleCustomerTemplates.CustId as MissingCustId,
       AllPossibleCustomerTemplates.TemplateId as MissingTemplateId
from AllPossibleCustomerTemplates 
left join ExistingCustomerTemplates ect ON ect.CustId = AllPossibleCustomerTemplates.CustId
                                        AND ect.TemplateId = AllPossibleCustomerTemplates.TemplateId
WHERE ect.CustId is null
```

Comment: This is a great idea.  Thank you.  The only problem is that the database has thousands of customers and so there are thousands of templates.  Doing the cross join would return millions of rows and so I'm not sure this is a practical solution.

Comment: Well I don't think you can get away from the database having to go through every customer and every template to see what is missing. I think it's worth a try as the Query optimiser should figure out how best to run your query. If it does perform slowly you may be able to add some indexes which is the next question ;) give it a go and see how performant it is.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query my friend:

```
with 
t1 as (select distinct TemplateID from Templates),
t2 as (select distinct CustID from Customers),
t3 as (select t2.*,t1.* from t2,t1),
t4 as (select * from t3 where
CustID+TemplateID not in 
(select CustID+TemplateID from Templates))
insert into Templates select * from t4;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/90730/12)

Comment: This is a really good query but my concern here is that the ultimately you end up with all possible templates instead of the missing ones so I would need to delete every template and replace it with the content of your t4 which in reality will be hundreds of thousands of rows.  Very intelligently done, though.

Comment: But `t4` returns the rows which are not in `Templates` and you can insert them in `templates`.

Comment: I'm running it on my test DB where there a 2143 customer rows and 2 templates where 5 templates are missing and T4 returns 4286 rows instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
with cte1 as
(
    select
        c.CustID, t.TemplateID
    from
        Customers c
    cross join
        (select distinct TemplateID from Templates) t
),
cte2 as
(
    select
        *
    from
        cte1
    where
        CustID + TemplateID not in(select CustID + TemplateID from Templates)
)

insert into Templates select * from cte2

select * from Templates order by CustID, TemplateID
```